# Visualising application of combination in probability

Tags: probability, combinations

A bag contains $3$ red balls, $4$ green balls, $5$ yellow balls. $3$ balls are taken out. What is the probability of picking at least 1 yellow ball?

I know the solution but the way I visualise the problem is, I see $12$ balls, I pick the first ball as yellow, I do it in $\binom{5}{1}$ ways, after that there are $11$ balls remaining, so ways of picking the remaining $2$ balls is $\binom{11}{2}$, of course divided by total number of possibilities which is $\binom{12}{1}$.

I do understand the $1$- no yellow method, but I want to understand how to intuitively visualise combination and probability in application problems.

Comment: In the second paragraph of your post, you describe how to find the probability of picking three balls, the first of which is yellow. Note that this is not the same as the probability of picking three balls and having at least one of them be yellow. Maybe you should explain what you mean by the "$1$- no yellow method".

Comment: 1- 7C3/12C3, as described below by JMoravitz

Comment: I've edited your post so that it now says $\binom{5}{1}$ instead of 5C1. Mathematicians will typically write $\binom{n}{m}$ instead of nCm.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you meant to divide by $\binom{12}{3}$, not $\binom{12}{1}$.

This is incorrect as it overcounts situations where you drew more than one yellow ball.

Compare this to the problem where you have only five yellow balls and no others in the box, and you pick three balls and you ask what the probability is that you picked at least one yellow ball.

Now... you should be able to tell me without doing any calculations whatsoever that we will always have picked at least one yellow ball... after all, there are only yellow balls available to be picked and we are picking more than one ball after all, so the probability is obviously $1$.

According to your broken logic however, we first pick a yellow ball, and then pick two more balls, then divide by the number of ways of picking three balls, giving a probability of $\dfrac{5\cdot \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{5}{3}} = 3$ which is not possible as a probability since it is greater than $1$ and is clearly not the correct answer.

Looking a bit more closely at what went wrong, again, you are overcounting.  Labeling the yellow balls $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5$, among the outcomes you counted was having picked $Y_1$ as the guaranteed yellow in the first step, followed by picking the pair $\{Y_2,Y_3\}$.  Also among the outcomes you counted was having picked $Y_2$ in the first step followed by picking the pair $\{Y_1,Y_3\}$.  These however are the same outcome.  In both of these outcomes we have the same triple of balls having been selected.  Your having split this into two steps incorrectly applied some sort of significance to which of the potentially many yellow balls was selected in the first step.

Now... back to your original problem... before you say "well then, let's just divide by the number of times we overcounted things" you will have overcounted each of the scenarios where you picked three yellow balls a total of three times... however with your method you correctly counted those scenarios where you drew exactly one yellow ball and did not overcount those scenarios.

If you insist, you could still approach directly if you like... but break into cases based on the total number of yellow balls that you picked.  It is easiest here to treat all balls as either "yellow" or "not-yellow", having combined the red and green categories together.

You'll get:

$$\dfrac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{7}{2}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{7}{1}+\binom{5}{3}\binom{7}{0}}{\binom{12}{3}}$$

which you will see is equal to $1-\dfrac{\binom{7}{3}}{\binom{12}{3}}$

Comment: Thank you, yes it is 12C3, I know that p>1 means something is wrong, I trying to understand how to understand. If 11C2 means yellow balls chosen are repeated, how is it that , in 5C1 x 7C2, green or red do not repeat, like wise for others... Basically I am trying to put down the balls, physically pick them and map it with the formula, I can't seem to understand the repetitions.

Comment: @Roopa I'll try saying it again... Yes, you want to count each possible outcome, and yes you did count each possible outcome.  Your mistake was that you counted some outcomes more than once when you didn't mean to.  That happened because by breaking into steps like you had you incorrectly applied some significance to whether a particular yellow ball was a yellow ball picked in the first step versus being a yellow ball picked in some later step.  You should be able to look at an overall outcome and be able to say uniquely what sequence of choices lead to that outcome...

Comment: But for the outcome $\{Y_1,Y_2,Y_3\}$ it is ambiguous whether this happened because $Y_1$ was picked in the first step and then $\{Y_2,Y_3\}$ were picked in the second step, or if $Y_2$ was picked in the first step and $\{Y_1,Y_3\}$ were picked in the second step, etc...